# Библиотека автоподсказок для интеграции с личным кабинет на битрикс

Tags: javascript, битрикс, битрикс24

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, библиотеку автоподсказок для интеграции с личным кабинет на битрикс.

- [Пример автоподсказки](https://pastenow.ru/b9cf2189a4856fc4b0019c5581c61462)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь вот [этим](https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/intervolga.tips/) готовым решением. Это готовый модуль для битрикса который позволяет к любому тексту на страницах сайта добавить поясняющий текст в виде всплывающей подсказки.

Чтобы иметь возможность выводить подсказки, управлять ими и их внешним видом на странице требуется разместить компонент "Активатор всплывающих подсказок". Рекомендуемый способ: разместить перед закрывающим тегом body вызов компонента:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
   "intervolga:tips.activator",
   "popover"
);?>
```

Компонент не выводит видимого html-кода, только шаблон подсказок в невидимом блоке.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]